# How do you call a parent function from a child component (with parameters) in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parameter-passing, parent-child

I have a react component called HomeHeader. Within HomeHeader lies a stateless component called SearchResultFlatList. Within SearchResultFlatList lies a stateless component called SearchListItem. **HomeHeader has 2 input fields (one for location and one for destination). Upon typing in an input field, SearchResultFlatList gets created and re-populated with SearchListItems (everytime I type something (think google search))**. When a SearchListItem is clicked, I would like to be able to call a function residing on HomeHeader. The functionality to be achieved is clicking a SearchListItem, and populating the respective input field on HomeHeader.

I have declared a function on HomeHeader called onLocationPress. It takes on one argument (ie. onLocationPress(locationValue)). It is very simple to pass down the reference to this function to the child components, but becomes more difficult when a variable is involved.

From HomeHeader.js

```
<SearchResultFlatList
   containerOpacity={this.state.opacityProp}
   headerExpanded={this.state.headerExpanded}
   results={this.props.searchResults}
   clickLocationResult={this.onLocationPress}
/>
```

From SearchResultFlatList.js

```
const SearchResultFlatList = (props) => {
    return(
        <Animated.View>
        <FlatList
          ....
            <SearchListItem
                clickLocationResult={props.clickLocationResult}
                primaryText={item.primaryText}
                fullText={item.fullText}
            />)}
          ....
        />
    </Animated.View>
    )
}
```

From SearchListItem.js

```
const SearchListItem = (props) => {

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.searchListItemContainer}
            onPress={props.clickLocationResult(props.primaryText)}
        >
        ....
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Calling it this way results in the function getting called soooo many times. I also have an `onTextChanged()` function on the input field, and everytime I type it logs the `props.primaryText` value.

**I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that everytime I type, new SearchListItems are getting created, but I don't know the work around.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a function to onPress with parameters. Instead define an arrow function that executes your clickLocationResult with the parameter like so.

```
const SearchListItem = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.searchListItemContainer}
      onPress={() => props.clickLocationResult(props.primaryText)}
    >
      ....
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yep - same outcome as mine and a clean approach.

Comment: Question: @Benjamin , if there were NO PARAMETERS, does it suffice just to use the way I did it? (eg. onPress={props.clickLocationResult})???? Is this implementation specific to using variables? If so please explain why

Comment: @JakeChambers yes, exactly! it's because onPress takes in a function as a parameter. `onPress={myFunction}` If you add parens after `myFunction` you are calling that function at the time the code is evaluated by the interpreter, and its return value is then given to `onPress` which isn't what we want. So imagine if we defined our function like so: `const myFunction = () => 'hello';` calling myFunction() returns 'hello'.

Comment: @JakeChambers ...continued. Then if we were to call it inside onPress like so: `onPress={myFunction()}`. The interpreter comes along, and executes myFunction, which returns 'hello', so now onPress receives 'hello' as its parameter: `onPress={'hello'}`, When the press event is fired, you will get an error, because it expected to receive a function, and instead received a string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what your function onLocationPress looks like in HomeHeader?

I am suspecting that what you need is something called function currying. There are a lot of resources out there on this, but the basic idea is that your function would be defined like this:

```
function onLocationPress(text) {
    // this is your click handler
    return () => {
        // do something with that text
    }
}
```

When you supply the onPress handler with a function with a parameter, that function is being EXECUTED and the result is being returned to the handler, as opposed to the function itself. What you want is for onLocationPress to be a function which **returns another function**.

Comment: Question: @Jaked222 if there were NO PARAMETERS, does it suffice just to use the way I did it? (eg. onPress={props.clickLocationResult})???? Is this implementation specific to using variables?

Comment: See Benjamin's comment. onPress is expecting a function. Giving it 'props.clickLocationResult' is a function. 'props.clickLocationResult(example)' is whatever clickLocationResult RETURNS. Good thing in javascript functions can return other functions.